# Difference between timestamps per day, with a night break in R

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, data.table, difftime

I am trying to calculate the difference between two timestamps and aggregate this per date and uid. I have calculated the difference for each time interval, but would like to split these intervals per day (so create some kind of midnight break). Given that the differences between time **intervals go overnight**, I am having trouble calculating the time between each interval per day, and thus these breaks.

Here's a snippet of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(
start_timestamp = c("2013-03-27 01:21:23", "2013-03-28 07:11:58", "2013-03-28 09:09:56", "2013-03-29 00:19:32", "2013-03-29 02:22:53"), 
uid = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
prev_start_timestamp = c("2013-03-27 01:13:26", "2013-03-27 05:58:53", "2013-03-28 08:41:41", "2013-03-28 10:47:01", "2013-03-29 02:17:26")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Usually I would work from this output and use *dplyr* or *data.table* to aggregate per day. but now, these time differences are simply calculated by substracting the time stamps. While, I want to have this differences split per day.

[image: output, undesired]

Expected output would be someting like this: But this one does not make any overnight breaks to separate the time each day.. this output indicates that some days have time intervals of longer than 24 hours, which is not possible of course..

[image]

Comment: Please show the expected result for your example input.

Comment: Not very useful. I precisely wanted to see output from data *with* overnight breaks.

Comment: The snippet of data looks unrepresentative, how are the call times supposed to be calculated? Is `prev_start_timestamp` the start time of a call and `start_timestamp` the end time?

Comment: I have no clue how to get that, that's why I am asking here

Comment: @DanielO True indeed, prev_start_time is beginning time and start_timestamp is end time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table::foverlaps`:

```
#create a data.table of daily intervals
datetimes <- DT[, seq(trunc(min(start), "days"), trunc(max(end)+24*60*60), "days")]
days <- data.table(start=datetimes[-length(datetimes)], end=datetimes[-1L], key=cols)

#set keys on original dataset and perform overlaps before calculating usage per day
setkeyv(DT, cols)
foverlaps(DT, days)[,
    .(phone_usage=sum(pmin(i.end, end) - pmax(i.start, start))), 
    .(uid, date=start)]
```

output (will leave to OP to check manually if this is correct for the sample dataset):

```
   uid       date phone_usage
1:   0 2013-03-27  65344 secs
2:   0 2013-03-28  75192 secs
3:   0 2013-03-29   1499 secs
```

data (note that i have shortened OP's column names):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
    end = c("2013-03-27 01:21:23", "2013-03-28 07:11:58", "2013-03-28 09:09:56", "2013-03-29 00:19:32", "2013-03-29 02:22:53"), 
    uid = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    start = c("2013-03-27 01:13:26", "2013-03-27 05:58:53", "2013-03-28 08:41:41", "2013-03-28 10:47:01", "2013-03-29 02:17:26"))
cols <- c('start', 'end')
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format="%Y-%m-%d %T"), .SDcols=cols]
```